# Automation for TVOS

Tags: xcode, instruments, tvos

I have a question regarding automation testing for **TVOS**.
Is it something that can be done with Xcode Automation Instruments?

I've tried to find any examples or documentation regarding automation processes for TVOS but nothing came out.
Is there anyone who can share info regarding this topic?

I have tried unsuccessfully to capture actions via Automation Instruments. Each time I try to capture, Instruments just get stuck.
It reproduces with several devices on several Macs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automation Instrument is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html) since Xcode 7.

It is recommended to use [Xcode UI Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH13-SW1) instead, which works for tvOS as well. You can record actions in the Xcode itself as described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH13-SW5).

Answer (score 0):

I use Xcode 8 version to run tests on ATV(tvOS) platforms. You can run specific tests on the tvOS simulator using Xcode.

If you are using ATV4 you can connect it to your mac directly and execute the tests on it using Xcode. However you cant do this on a ATV3 platform.